# Javascript: Add Onload function to POST Popup page

Tags: javascript, forms, popup, submit, onload

First post here. I have a problem I CANNOT solve.
I have a popup window (window.open). Let's say that opens "1.php". It has a form that submits to "2.php" after a button whose Id is "Submit" is clicked.

It is easy to add an Onload function toa  popup:

```
open_window = window.open("1.php", "",'width=100,height=100,location=0');   
open_window.addEventListener("load", function(){//do something}, false);
```

But I WANT something different. I want this:

```
open_window = window.open("1.php", "",'width=100,height=100,location=0');

// a lot of thing happen. then after certain action, another function does this:

open_window.document.getElementById("Submit").click(); //submits to "2.php"


open_window.addEventListener("load", function(){//DO SOMETHING AFTER 2.PHP HAS LOADED}, false);
```

This last command does not work. I have 1.php that is already loaded. then submit the form to 2.php and insert an OnLoad to 2.php. The form DOES submit but onload does not execute.

Any ideas? i tried the equivalent with iframe and it works

I appreciate any help.

Danny

Comment: Anyone please? I REALLY tried to look everywhere with no luck. Thanks again.

Comment: anyone PLEASE? I promise I cannot find the answer to this problem! I looked everywhere